# Which one is better launching service in normal way(startService()) or by using startForeground()

Tags: android

I am launching a service in my app.Currently I am starting my service in my activity in a simple way:

```
Intent i=new Intent(this,WindowService.class);
startService(i);
```

It works fine in most of the devices,But in some devices like lenovo and some devices when I remove my app from recent tasks the service also gets killed with activity.So I found that `startForeground()` method will solve this issue.Is it true that `startForeground()` method allows my service run even if the application is removed from recent tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its true, `startForeground()` started a foregrounded service with notification which show the user that the service still running. This is because a foregrounded service consumes a heavier amount of resources and is subject to different scheduling constraints (i.e., it doesn't get killed as quickly) than background services.

the common used its for playing music, download files and etc.

Answer (score 0):

From [Service Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)

> A started service can use the startForeground(int, Notification) API
>   to put the service in a foreground state, where the system considers
>   it to be something the user is actively aware of **and thus not a
>   candidate for killing when low on memory**. (It is still theoretically
>   possible for the service to be killed under extreme memory pressure
>   from the current foreground application, but in practice this should
>   not be a concern.)

so from the docs it seems the system will not kill the foreground service